# Setup Entourage for Exchange via HTTP communication

Tags: macos, mac, email, exchange, entourage

Our ISP set up a hosted exchange server for all our mail. I've setup all our Outlook users with no problems.

We have two people using Mac OSX Leopard and Entourage.

Entourage has the option of adding an Exchange account, but I have no idea how to tell it to connect to exchange via HTTP.

Heres an excerpt from the client setup docs the hosting company sent me for Outlook:

1 .Go to control panel 2. Select ‘Mail’ 3. Select ‘Email accounts’

1. Under the E-mail tab select ‘New’
2. Select ‘Manually configure server settings......’ - click next
3. Select ‘Microsoft Exchange’ – click next
4. Complete details as below with Microsoft Exchange Server as: [server address]
5. Do not select ‘Check Name’. Instead select ‘More Settings’.
6. Go to the Connection tab, and select the bottom option ‘Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP’. And then select the ‘Exchange Proxy Settings’ button.
7. Enter Proxy server for Exchange
8. Check Only connect to proxy servers that have this principal name in their certificate, Enter msstd:[servername]
9. Proxy Authentication - select Basic Authentication

   10. Select OK, and again, so that you return to the main screen. Now select ‘Check Name’.
   11. Enter Username and Password:
   12. The username should now be the full name and underlined. If so select next, and then finish.
   13. Next time you open Outlook, enter username and password

Any help GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like directions for the PC.

Entourage -> Account Settings -> New Account -> Exchange -> Manual

Put the OWA server (or URL) into the Server tab.

You may need to fiddle with SSL or not, but there is a test option for your connection.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

For authentication, select "**Use my account information**":

**Account id**: username@domain.com 
**Password**: passwordhere 
**Exchange Server**: https://my.exchange.server.name/exchange/username@domain.com

Select checkbox for "**This DAV service requires a secure connection**"

I'm using Entourage from Office 2008 for Mac